# Trouble getting location data using LTE rather than WiFi

Tags: java, android, location, locationmanager, locationlistener

I am trying to get the Lat/Long for the device when using 4G/LTE. The code below works great when using WiFi but the `onLocationChanged` method doesn't get called at all when using 4G/LTE. Any idea why?

I only have a limited window to get the location coordinates as they need to be appended to an audit log at the beginning.

Does LTE/4G usually take much longer than WiFi to pinpoint the lat/long?

```
lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);



if (networkType.equals("WiFi")) {
    lp = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
}
else {
    lp = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
}


locationListener = new LocationListener() {
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
         gpsTestLocation = locationStringFromLocation(location);
         System.out.println("mcsoutput location: " + gpsTestLocation);
        }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {


    }
    };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(lp, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Network Type is figured out by:

```
private String checkNetworkState() {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    //  NetworkInfo mEthernet = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET);
        NetworkInfo m3G = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        TelephonyManager telephonyService = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);


        if (mWifi!=null) isOnWifi = mWifi.isConnected();
        if (m3G!=null) is3G = m3G.isConnected();

        if(isOnWifi == true) {
            return "WiFi";
        }
        else {
            int cellType = telephonyService.getNetworkType();
            return isConnectionFast(cellType);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but isn't networkType.equals("WiFi") causing the issue?
What is networkType? How do you get it?

Comment: I've added the method used to determine network type. I debugged the code to make sure it was working as expected, and it is. Just for some reason the location isn't being received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using NETWORK_PROVIDER when on wifi and GPS when off.  Odds are you aren't getting a GPS synch.  Its actually very hard to do when indoors.  Are you getting a flashing GPS symbol in your notification bar?  If so, you aren't getting a full GPS synch and thus onLocationChanged won't be called.

When on wifi using NETWORK_PROVIDER you'll get an almost instant location because NETWORK_PROVIDER needs no satellites and is almost always available, it just isn't nearly as accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll drag the laptop to the roof and see if I have better luck. I am seeing the flashing you mention.

Comment: You'll know you have a synch when it becomes solid.  Or you can use GpsTest (its a free app) to get more info on your state.  Alternatively, you can download an app like FakeGPS and enable mock locations for your app to be able to send fake GPS co-ordinates to it.